# How do I bulk switch specific content from one content type to another?

Tags: nodes

So I get a fair amount of spam on my site that gets a good amount of traffic. But the spam content doesn't fit what my main audience is looking for. So I created a content section called spam and downloaded the [Node_Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) module, which has worked out well. I can easy change content from one type to another individually. But I want to bulk switch specific content from on type to another. I know I can bulk switch a content type using this module, but I don't want to switch a whole content type, just specific articles in one content type to the Spam content type all at once. It would make sense to to this from the admin content dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can bulk switch a content type using this module, but I don't want to switch a whole content type, just specific articles in one content type to the Spam content type all at once. It would make sense to to this from the admin content dashboard.

Node Convert lets you create a custom action to perform this task. You may cherry-pick any items you want to convert and convert them. You need not convert *all* content from 1 content type.

This feature is in Admin -> Content.

Be sure you have tried installing the various dependencies. In this case probably Rules and maybe VBO:

> The module integrates with Actions, Rules, Views Bulk Operations and Admin Views nicely. It has support for exporting templates into Features using CTools Exportables.